# What does pivot_table do when not given columns to pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF "users" that stores this data:

```
  weekday    city  visitors  signups
0     Sun  Austin       139        7
1     Sun  Dallas       237       12
2     Mon  Austin       326        3
3     Mon  Dallas       456        5
```

And I don't understand the output of this:

```
users.pivot_table(index ='weekday')
```

The output:

```
         signups  visitors
weekday                   
Mon          4.0       391
Sun          9.5       188
```

I know that the default function that pivot_table aggregates with is the `mean()`.
I just don't understand the way it "pivots" the table.
Why doesn't the city appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `pivot_table` behavior acts on all non-key columns and internally calls `groupby.agg` ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3adf3340453d6704d4a2cb47058214cc697a7d29/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L100)). If there are columns on which the `agg` cannot call the function (in this case, `mean`), it looks like `agg` just ignores them ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1a23779f09abc6ebf908d66ee88b973b767e2e3c/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L4172)). Here's a silly example where we change the function to accept strings or numbers, and `pivot_table` works on all columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def custom_mean(l):
    if type(l.iloc[0]) == str:
        return ''.join(l)
    else:
        return np.mean(l)

df = pd.DataFrame({'weekday':  ['Sun', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Mon'],
                   'city':     ['Austin', 'Dallas', 'Austin', 'Dallas'],
                   'visitors': [139, 237, 326, 456],
                   'signups':  [7, 12, 3, 5]})


print(df.pivot_table(index = 'weekday', aggfunc = custom_mean))
```

Output:

```
                 city  signups  visitors
weekday                                 
Mon      AustinDallas      4.0       391
Sun      AustinDallas      9.5       188
```